# Android Studio - Error al registrar nuevo usuario con google

Tags: android, android-studio, google-oauth, firebase-auth

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi aplicación para android en la cual he implementado el sistema de registro de usuarios a través de la cuenta de google.

Todo estaba funcionando correctamente realizando una instalación directamente con el archivo apk generado, pero el problema ha aparecido al publicar la aplicación en google play y es que al instalar la misma en un dispositivo, no permite registrar nuevos usuarios, ya que se produce el siguiente error en el momento de creación de la cuenta:

E/ActivityTrigger(1734): activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.rutillastoby.zoria/com.rutillastoby.zoa.LoginActivity/2

Alguien se ha encontrado en algún momento con un error similar o conoce lo que puede estar fallando?
Muchas gracias

**Esta es el log de la ejecución en el momento del registro de una cuenta nueva**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: "registro de usuarios a través de la cuenta de google.", ¿te refieres a el registro mediante Firebase?

Comment: @Jorgesys Si, exacto!